# Redirecting JS logs to Java

Tags: java, javascript, javafx, javafx-webengine

Using [`javafx.scene.web.WebEngine#setOnAlert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html), i'm able to access `alert` calls made in Javascript via Java :

```
myWebEngine.setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(WebEvent<String> alert) {
    logger.info(alert.getData()); // logs the message displayed in alert
});
```

However, I also test my application in standard browsers such as Firefox, and would rather use the `console`, ie : transforming `alert('test')` into `console.log('test')`.

Is there an already existing implementation of such a feature ?